# What to do if other users are not accepting the answer?

Tags: support

For many questions, I posted the answers. One person said that this was correct and this solved the issue, but they are not accepting the answer. Still they are saying that this helped me in comments. What should I do in such a situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this occurs mainly with new users who don't even know about accepting answers, or those who don't even care about it.

The best thing to do would be to advise the OP with comments about accepting answers, and also tell them to read the link below and also other guidance's in the SO [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ( But, as @Deduplicator said, make sure to check the OP's profile to see if they are new, or if they have asked a few questions before and have not accepted any answers, but commented that the answer is what they wanted , otherwise, don't do it )

[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Other than that, there's not much you can do. If your answer is a good one, then the other members of the SO community will upvote your answer. But it is upto the OP to accept answers.

Even if the OP does not accept it, if your answer is highly upvoted, that itself means that the community considers your answer to be good, and I believe that is a good thing. A lot of the time, there are answers with a higher score than an accepted answer because the community likes it more. An accepted answer is the one the OP found useful, it need not always be the best answer . So, that itself proves that your answer is a good one.

So as mentioned before, you can just direct the OP in the right way by informing him/her about accepting answers.